# How do I use Ajax and Jquery to get an array from PHP and post it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I am using a separate PHP file as a configuration file for everything else on a basic ecommerce site.

Here is config/products.php:

```
$product1["short"] = "product one";
$product1["menuimgslideshowsrc"] = "image/product1.jpg";
```

When I hover over a button, I want to get `$product1["menuimgslideshowsrc"]` and swap it out with an IMG SRC.

I can do the swapping no problem, I need to know how to get the information stored in `$product1["menuimgslideshowsrc"]`. I assume I would use Ajax, but I am open to other ideas.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Current code

```
    $( '.leftMenuProductButton' ).hover (
            function () {

                var currentIMG = $("#swapImg").attr("src");

                $("#swapImg").attr("src").replace(currentIMG, "NEWIMAGE");


            },
            function () {





    });
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Edited - need to get PHP `$product1["menuimgslideshowsrc"]` and put it where NEWIMAGE is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jared, how about rendering products.php as a javascript array and including it in your page? Then you can just reference "menuimgslideshowsrc" directly from your jquery method.

products.php returns:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var productImages = new Array();
  productImages["menuimgslideshowsrc"] = "image/product1.jpg";
</script>
```

Your method becomes:

```
$( '.leftMenuProductButton' ).hover (
            function () {

                var currentIMG = $("#swapImg").attr("src");

                $("#swapImg").attr("src").replace(currentIMG, productImages["menuimgslideshowsrc"]);


        },
        function () {
```

Comment: because sometimes the simplest of solutions escape me! Thank you!